# Windows Phone VB Web Request

Tags: vb.net, rest, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

does anybody has an idea how I can perform an asynchronus Post Request in VB.Net for Windows Phone 8?

I tried a lot but nothing worked... also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx didn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post code you've tried and the results?

Comment: I have tried this code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx (Can't post it here... too long)

Comment: Results were nothing... i am not sure what the problem is :(

Answer (score 2):

I had to figure this out for myself a while ago. Let me see what I can do to help.

Posting a web request is actually simpler than that link shows. Here's what I do.

First, I create a MultipartFormDataContent:

```
Dim form as New MultipartFormDataContent()
```

Next, I add each string I want to send like this:

```
form.Add(New StringContent("String to sent"), "name of the string you are sending")
```

Next, create a HttpClient:

```
Dim httpClient as HttpClient = new HttpClient()
```

Next, we'll create a HttpResponseMessage and post your information to the url of your choice:

```
Dim response as HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.PostAsync("www.yoururl.com/wherever", form)
```

Then, I usually need the response as a string, so I read the response to a string:

```
Dim responseString as String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

This will give you the response you wanted, if that's what you wanted.

Here's an example of a method I use:

```
Public Async Function GetItems() As Task
    Dim getUrl As String = "https://myapiurl.com/v3/get"
    Dim responseText As String = String.Empty
    Dim detailType As String = "complete"
    Try
        Dim httpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Dim form As New MultipartFormDataContent()
        form.Add(New StringContent(roamingSettings.Values("ConsumerKey").ToString()), "consumer_key")
        form.Add(New StringContent(roamingSettings.Values("access_token").ToString()), "access_token")
        form.Add(New StringContent(detailType.ToString()), "detailType")
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.PostAsync(getUrl, form)
        responseText = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function
```

If you aren't using the Http client libraries, you need to install them like this:
What you need to do to use the HttpClient, is to navigate in Visual Studio, go to Tools->Library Package Manager->Manage Nuget Packages for this solution. When there, search the online section for HttpClient and make sure you have "Include Prerelease" selected in the listbox above the results. (Default is set to "Stable Only")
Then install the package with the ID of Microsoft.Net.Http

Then you'll need to add an Import statement at the beginning of the document you are using it in.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Thanks,
SonofNun

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I try your code i get an error "Type "HttpClient" is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my answer with more information on the HttpClient.